# BizTalk and COM+

Tags: .net, interop, biztalk, com+

We have a legacy CRM system which can only send out events to COM+ components.

This is done via a component written in VB6 so it we are very limited in what we can do with it.

We have a legacy custom written Delphi interop COM+ component which passes these event messages to our other sub-systems as SOAP messages.

We are replacing this interop with BizTalk so we need BizTalk to action these events.

Our current planned solution is to write a custom .Net COM+ component which simply passes the messages through to a WCF net.tcp Receive Port.

Is it possible to have a BizTalk Receive Port directly configured as a COM+ component to remove the need for our small interface layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not out of the box.

You can write a custom Adapter than wraps the COM+ comp and submits messages to you BizTalk app.

However, your current plan is more than serviceable so I would stick with that.